# How to repeat lines in bash and paste with different columns?

Tags: bash, file, awk, paste, data-manipulation

is there a short way in bash to repeat the first line of a file as often as needed to paste it with another file in a kronecker product type (for the mathematicians of you)?
What I mean is, I have a file A:

```
    a
    b
    c
```

and a file B:

```
    x
    y
    z
```

and I want to merge them as follows:

```
    a x
    a y 
    a z
    b x
    b y
    b z
    c x
    c y
    c z
```

I could probably write a script, read the files line by line and loop over them, but I am wondering if there a short one-line command that could do the same job. I can't think of one and as you can see, I am also lacking some keywords to search for. :-D

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this one-liner awk command:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[++n]=$0; next} {for(i=1; i<=n; i++) print $0, a[i]}' file2 file1
a x
a y
a z
b x
b y
b z
c x
c y
c z
```

**Breakup**:

```
NR == FNR {                  # While processing the first file in the list
  a[++n]=$0                  # store the row in array 'a' by the an incrementing index
  next                       # move to next record
}
{                            # while processing the second file 
  for(i=1; i<=n; i++)        # iterate over the array a
  print $0, a[i]             # print current row and array element
}
```

Comment: Wow, I knew awk is great. I really need to learn a bit more of how to use it. Thanks, this works.

Answer (score 0):

alternative to awk

```
join <(sed 's/^/_\t/' file1) <(sed 's/^/_\t/' file2) | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

add a fake key for `join` to have all records of file1 to match all records of file2, trim afterwards